# Using web sphere server, Can we update and read file from the deployed .war/.ear/. files?

Tags: java, servlets, deployment, websphere, digital-signature

This is structure in my local(before deployment) :

[image]

To access key.doc file using below path

```
String filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "\\FORM22-INDIA";

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

ks.load(new FileInputStream(filePath + "\\key.doc"), PASSWORD);
```

but after deployment , getting File Not Found exception, while accessing key.doc file.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing a web application resource, you can use ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() API.

Code:

```
InputStream st= getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/FORM22-INDIA/key.doc");
```

Also, it's not a good idea to keep files(which you intend to update) in your WAR or EAR  as your changes will be lost as soon as you redeploy the application.

Comment: Suppose I want to update , Form22.pdf in the above directory, will .EAR file allow to update??

Comment: used getResourceStream, getting null(inplace of FileNotFound Exception). getting [java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained

Comment: its working , but we have to place inside WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I'm sorry couldn't get back to your comment. Glad to hear that it's working for you. Happy coding.